# Specify a conversion for an interface with automapper

Tags: automapper

Most of my EF objects have a TenantId Property. The system never have to handle the tenantId it's all taken care for before the SaveChanges(). I want to write an automapper map that will always ignore the TenantId Field.

I've tried

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IDomainObject, ITenantData>()
      .ForMember(m => m.TenantId, a => a.Ignore());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it using [mapping inheritance](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance). For instance:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IDomainObject, ITenantData>()
  .Include<DomainObject1, TenantData1>()
  .ForMember(m => m.TenantId, a => a.Ignore());
```